# Update operation onClick of an icon

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, crud

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.edit-name').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('div').find('span,input').toggle();
 });
 var name = $('#name').val();    
 $('#submit').on('click', function(){
   $('#result').html($('#name').val());     
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<button type='submit' id="submit"> Save </button>
<div class="editable">
  <span>First Name</span>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="First Name" style="display:none;"/>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg edit-name" aria-hidden="true">edit</i>
</div>
```

I am trying to figure out how this would work, so any help is appreciated.

I have the following code snippet:

```
<?php
 echo $name . '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
 echo $Age . '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
?>
```

I should be able to click that icon and change that variable with AJAX. I can figure out the ajax part myself with no issues.

I am having issues with trying to figure out if I should be fetching just `$name` or it should be an `<input>`.

Comment: No need for an `<input>` but you might like to wrap it in something, either a `<span>` or `<div>` then you can give it an id/class and wire your events accordingly.  eg `echo '<div class="edit">' . $name . '<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></div>'`

Comment: Hi, its really not clear exactly what you are trying to do here. Can you add a bit more explanation please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML like,

```
<div class="editable">
   <span><?php echo $name?></span>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>" style="display:none"/>
   <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o edit-name" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<div>
```

And in jQuery,

```
$(function(){
     $('.edit-name').on('click',function(){
         $(this).closest('div').find('span,input').toggle();
     });
});
```

Then change name field in textbox and submit by using AJAX.

**Update,** change your submit click event like,

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
   $('#result').html($('#name').val());
});
```

Comment: Or no input and just `var name = $(this).prev().text()`

Comment: Awesome answer, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Ill accept when it lets me.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar if the input value is set as the PHp echo then it will never change in the AJAX submit, how do I get around that?

Comment: You have required to change the value of input by clicking on pencil icon, then only you can change the textbox value.

Comment: @RohanKumar No, all that part works. But then when I set the jquery var like this `var name = $('#name').val();` it just sets it to the original value. It's not setting it to the new value I entered in the input box.

Comment: Can you make a snippet/fiddle for it?

Comment: and I have to create that var to add it to my ajax call.

Comment: Yes, one second.

Comment: @RohanKumar As you can see now, when you change the name and hit save, the var is still the original var.

Comment: Any info on this?

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Comment: I don't understand why that works, isn't the var "name" the exact same thing?

Comment: It is because the name variable will get the last value when your page is loaded. So after changing the name in textbox the variable doesn't change, hence you were getting the old value.